# How To Extract The Name of the Level 7 HTTP2 Application in Tshark

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tshark

So by default when you open a pcap in wireshark it looks something like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr4sZ.png)

But I want to view the name of the websites, so I have to find the host (HTTP) or :authority (HTTP2) header then apply it as a column so that I have the name of the website in my display. Once that is done I can export the pcap as a CSV with the name of the websites include CSV.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cNFP.png)

My question is how do I do this in tshark? Especially for HTTP2. There's lot's of information on how to do this for HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`tshark` man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html):

> -T ek|fields|json|jsonraw|pdml|ps|psml|tabs|text
>
> ...
>
> fields The values of fields specified with the -e option, in a form
> specified by the -E option. For example,
>
> tshark -T fields -E separator=, -E quote=d

So in your case, you might use something like:

```
tshark -r Wednesday.pcap -Y http2 -T fields -E separator=, -E quote=d -e frame.number -e frame.time_relative -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e _ws.col.Protocol -e frame.len -e http2.headers.authority -e _ws.col.Info > Wednesday.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll read the man page religously from now on.